# Confusion over unittest assert with class type expectation

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core

Im using .netcore5 and Moq library,im trying to write a test for a method which retunes:

```
 public  class CheckResult
{

    public bool ShouldBeFlagged { get; set; } = default!;
    public decimal ExeededAmount { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

so,when it comes to assert how should i apply it to the class?my expected result is:

```
shouldBeFlagged=true;
ExeededAmount=2000M;
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: `Assert.True(result.ShouldBeFlagged); Assert.Equals(2000M, result.ExceededAmount);`

Comment: @DavidG thanks a lot,so i should write asset as many as my class properties